# Mybatis mapping list of objects

Tags: mybatis

I have the following two classes

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Account> accounts
}

public class Account {
    private String id;
}
```

I have the following mybatis resultMap

```
<resultMap id="User" type="User">
    <result property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <collection property="accounts" ofType="Account">
        <result property="id" column="accont_id"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

And I have two tables *user* and *user_account*

How do I get a User with all fields covered with one call using myBatis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need mark the id attributes in the parent object using the id tag instead the result tag.

```
<resultMap id="User" type="User">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <collection property="accounts" ofType="Account">
        <result property="id" column="accont_id"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```